# git push not finding host

Tags: git, github, push

I am attempting to push to a remote repo that I have already been pushing to, however now I am getting an error I don't understand.

```
git push
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Then I did a `git status`

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Then I ran `git remote -v`

```
origin  git@github.com:<username>/<projectName>.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:<username>/<projectName>.git (push)
```

I would greatly appreciate some guidance. My gut tells me this isn't a git issue but some networking issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And you are sure you have internet connection?

Comment: @DavidConrad @barceloco The response `ping: cannot resolve github.com: Unknown host` , but in the browser I have full access. Any ideas?

Comment: you are basically telling ping to ping a machine that responds with the name "git" which obviously doesn't exist. Unless you have one called like that in your local network.

Comment: On my machine `ping github.com` and `ping www.github.com` work. My guess is that you are using a network that blocks many ports. Where are you trying to do this? At an airport? At an internet cafe?... If you have full browser access, it seems to me as if your network just allowed http and https connections, but no github, for example.

Comment: sounds like you have blocked port 22. How were you able to push to the repo before? Try this to find out if port 22 is open in your network: http://canyouseeme.org/

Comment: Can you view github.com in your browser? If yes, your connection to github.com works, but the port used for pushing must be blocked by a firewall somewhere on the way. Try to temporarily disable your firewall, or configure your router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is some bug with the Apple's `discoveryd` process. I read about the problem [Here](http://furbo.org/2015/05/05/discoveryd-clusterfuck/) and [Here](http://www.imore.com/still-plugging-leaks-os-x-yosemite-boat-problem-discoveryd)

I killed the process, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use 'git' protocol to fetch/push. By default it uses 9418 port to connect. Refer to [Git Protocol Docs](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols). Some firewall setting must be blocking this port, or just the port that is assigned to this protocol. Either look in firewall settings or attempt to clone via ssh rather than GIT like this:

```
git remote set-url --push origin ssh://github.com:<username>/<projectName>.git (push)
```

Syntax may need corrections though.