# Please make sure you have the correct access right and the repository exists github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, ssh

When I try to push my changes to my github repo I am receiving the error:

> Fatal: 'git@github.comRedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git' does not appear to be a git repository
>   Fatal: could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I have looked at the documentation and completed the steps here:https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/

As well as looked at other sites and nothing is working. I am able to connect to ssh because I receive the message :Hi RedHoodJT1988...

I am at a loss for what to do next. I am not using a cloud IDE I am on a macbook pro if that helps. Also, not sure if it matters, I am developing a Ruby on Rails application.

Comment: Should not be your ssh clone link will be like `git@github.com:RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git` instead of `git@github.comRedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git`?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` return?

Comment: it shows origin git@github.comRedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git (fetch)

Comment: origin git@github.comRedHoodJT1988/hello_app (push)

Comment: You're missing the colon. I'll add a solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a colon in your address and need to change your remote named origin

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git
```

Comment: So I am now getting a different error

ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:redhoodjt1988: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: Can you try readding the remote using the https url?
`https://github.com/RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git`

So

`git remote remove origin`
`git remote add origin https://github.com/RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git`

Comment: When I run the git remote -v it produces the result
origin https://github.com:RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git.gitRedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git (push)

Comment: Are you getting that from `git remote -v` after changing the remote to use the https address?

Comment: Is there a way to fix that? I know that it can't be right.

Comment: when you run `git remote remove origin` and then `git remote -v` what do you get?

Comment: It produces nothing.

Comment: Then after `git remote add origin https://github.com/RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git'`

What does `git remote -v` return?

Comment: It produces: 
origin https://github.com/RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.gitRedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git (push)

Comment: In a brand new directory, one without an existing git config, can you try cloning another one of your private repos on github? Ie. `git clone https://github.com/RedHoodJT1988/<repo>.git` ?

Comment: I'm still a bit new to git. When you say new directory do I just create a new one using mkdir <directory> then cd to <directory> and run git init?

Comment: Before you do that, and if you're working on a mac, does killing the process `discoveryd` on your mac help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215254/git-push-not-finding-host#answer-32220298

Comment: How do I kill a process? I'm new to Mac.

Comment: `killall discoveryd`

Comment: I am now getting a different error that says RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.gitRedHoodJT1988/hello_app is not a valid repository name Email support@github.com for help.

Comment: I received the message : "No matching processes belonging to you were found"

Comment: `RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.gitRedHoodJT1988/hello_app` is not a valid repo. Your repo should be `RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git`

I see now in your comment above that is being returned as the push remote for origin.

I hate to ask, but I'd try to remove and add origin remote again using the steps in my question answer.

Comment: I was able to get it. I used git remote remove origin
then used the command from my repository to push it.
Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity and for my benefit, what was the "command from my repository"?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an SSH URL, there should not be any https involved:

```
 git remote set-url origin git@github.com:RedHoodJT1988/hello_app.git
```